# I can't 'npm run release', that show error no 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

When I use `npm run release` to release my project, I get an error message:

```
> react-scaffold@1.0.0 release 
/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc
> gulp release

assert.js:42
throw new errors.AssertionError({
^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask]                     (/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task (/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc/gulpfile.js:36:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-scaffold@1.0.0 release: `gulp release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-scaffold@1.0.0 release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional     logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nick/.npm/_logs/2018-11-16T06_59_44_162Z-debug.log
```

Then I cat the file `/home/nick/.npm/_logs/2018-11-16T06_59_44_162Z-debug.log`:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'run', 'release' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v8.12.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prerelease', 'release', 'postrelease' ]
5 info lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~prerelease: react-scaffold@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~release: react-scaffold@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~release: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~release: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc/node_modules/.bin:/home/nick/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~release: CWD: /home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc
10 silly lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~release: Args: [ '-c', 'gulp release' ]
11 silly lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~release: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle react-scaffold@1.0.0~release: Failed to exec release script
13 verbose stack Error: react-scaffold@1.0.0 release: `gulp release`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid react-scaffold@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc
16 verbose Linux 4.15.0-36-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "release"
18 verbose node v8.12.0
19 verbose npm  v6.4.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error react-scaffold@1.0.0 release: `gulp release`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the react-scaffold@1.0.0 release script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And I try 'gulp release', it shows an error, too:

```
assert.js:42
throw new errors.AssertionError({
^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask]     (/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc/node_modules/undertaker/lib/se    t-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task     (/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc/node_modules/undertaker/lib/ta    sk.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous>     (/home/nick/code/ops_order_system/ops_order/fesrc/gulpfile.js:36:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

The version is

```
node: v8.12.0
npm: 6.4.1
gulp: CLI version 2.0.1
      Local version 4.0.0
```

I try many ways to solve this error, but no one is work. I really want to know how to solve this problem!

Before I asked this question, I have tried `npm cache clear --force rm -rf node_modules npm install`, but it did not work for me, either. I also used root to run these command above, but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

I already know why. I should install gulp -g.
use `npm install -g gulp`  it work for me.